# Can we recover a number from the values of Mobius function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

All:

We are considering a question. If we know the values of Mobius function for all numbers less than $n$, can we recover $n$ from all of those Mobius function values?

Essentially, we want to know if we can write $n$ as a function of $u(1), u(2), \ldots, u(n-1)$, where $u(i)$ is the value of Mobius function of integer $i$.

Thank you.

Comment: Not very satisfying but $n = \text{length}(u(1), u(2), \ldots, u(n-1)) + 1$.

Comment: Maybe more satisfying if we change the question so that we only know the values of $\mu(n)$ between $n-\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ and $n-1$?  Then all we know immediately is that $n$ is about a square of the length.

Comment: My initial instinct is that just knowing $|\mu(n-1)|, \dots, |\mu(n-m)|$ for $m$ around $(\log n)^2$ (or some power of log) is enough to reconstruct $n$: that seems like enough information to determine what $n$ is modulo $4$, $9$, ... - modulo enough small primes that the Chinese remainder theorem does the rest. Can someone flesh this out?